# Algorithms for testing a poker hand for a straight draw (4 to a straight)?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, poker

I'm in the throes of writing a poker evaluation library for fun and am looking to add the ability to test for draws (open ended, gutshot) for a given set of cards.

Just wondering what the "state of the art" is for this?  I'm trying to keep my memory footprint reasonable, so the idea of using a look up table doesn't sit well but could be a necessary evil.

*My current plan is along the lines of:*

- subtract the lowest rank from the rank of all cards in the set.
- look to see if certain sequence i.e.: 0,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4 (for OESDs) is a subset of the modified collection.

I'm hoping to do better complexity wise, as 7 card or 9 card sets will grind things to a halt using my approach.

Any input and/or better ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for us that doesn't play poker, what is draws?

Comment: @Gorgen A straight is 5 cards of subsequent ranks (eg, A 2 3 4 5 or 9 10 J Q K). A draw is four out of the required 5 cards in a straight. An 'open ended' draw means the 4 cards are sequential and don't include A - eg, 2 3 4 5 or 8 9 10 J. An 'inside' draw means the cards aren't sequential or do include A - eg, 2 3 5 6 or A 2 3 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest approach probably to assign a bit mask for each card rank (e.g. deuce=1, three=2, four=4, five=8, six=16, seven=32, eight=64, nine=128, ten=256, jack=512, queen=1024, king=2048, ace=4096), and OR together the mask values of all the cards in the hand.  Then use an 8192-element lookup table to indicate whether the hand is a straight, an open-ender, a gut-shot, or a nothing of significance (one could also include the various types of backdoor straight draw without affecting execution time).

Incidentally, using different bitmask values, one can quickly detect other useful hands like two-of-a-kind, three-of-a-kind, etc.  If one has 64-bit integer math available, use the cube of the indicated bit masks above (so deuce=1, three=8, etc. up to ace=2^36) and add together the values of the cards.  If the result, and'ed with 04444444444444 (octal) is non-zero, the hand is a four-of-a kind.  Otherwise, if adding plus 01111111111111, and and'ing with 04444444444444 yields non-zero, the hand is a three-of-a-kind or full-house.  Otherwise, if the result, and'ed with 02222222222222 is non-zero, the hand is either a pair or two-pair.  To see if a hand contains two or more pairs, 'and' the hand value with 02222222222222, and save that value.  Subtract 1, and 'and' the result with the saved value.  If non-zero, the hand contains at least two pairs (so if it contains a three-of-a-kind, it's a full house; otherwise it's two-pair).

As a parting note, the computation done to check for a straight will also let you determine quickly how many different ranks of card are in the hand.  If there are N cards and N different ranks, the hand cannot contain any pairs or better (but might contain a straight or flush, of course).  If there are N-1 different ranks, the hand contains precisely one pair.  Only if there are fewer different ranks must one use more sophisticated logic (if there are N-2, the hand could be two-pair or three-of-a-kind; if N-3 or fewer, the hand could be a "three-pair" (scores as two-pair), full house, or four-of-a-kind).

One more thing: if you can't manage an 8192-element lookup table, you could use a 512-element lookup table.  Compute the bitmask as above, and then do lookups on array[bitmask & 511] and array[bitmask >> 4], and OR the results.  Any legitimate straight or draw will register on one or other lookup.  Note that this won't directly give you the number of different ranks (since cards six through ten will get counted in both lookups) but one more lookup to the same array (using array[bitmask >> 9]) would count just the jacks through aces.

Comment: Great input.  Never thought of using masks like this.  Have really only been using them to test for flushes.

Comment: Could be great if this answer explains how to create the lookup table.

Comment: @Riverside: Take the bit value for all of the cards in each possible hand, "or" them together to get the table index, and have that slot in the table indicate the worth of the hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I'd need an example. I have 3678T so the mask is `101110010` and the closest straight is 6789T `111110000`. What do I need in my LUT to say that 3678T is a straight draw? Do I need to mark every single mask manually? I mean, how do I mark in my LUT that `101110010` is a straight draw? You might say that my LUT should only contain straight draw masks, but first, how do I create this table that contains only straight draws masks automatically? Sorry if I'm missing an obvious point here.

Comment: @Riverside: To produce a the set of bitmasks for four-card straight draw hands, take the set of ten five-card straight bitmasks and, for each of them, add the bitmask that is formed by clearing each of the bits.  Then given that list, one can form a set of five card hands that contain straight draws by taking each bitmask and adding to the list all of the bitmasks that can be formed by setting one more bit.

Answer (score 7):

I know you said you want to keep the memory footprint as small as possible, but there is one quite memory efficient lookup table optimization which I've seen used in some poker hand evaluators and I have used it myself. If you're doing heavy poker simulations and need the best possible performance, you might wanna consider this. Though I admit in this case the difference isn't that big because testing for a straight draw isn't very expensive operation, but the same principle can be used for pretty much every type of hand evaluation in poker programming.

The idea is that we create a kind of a hash function that has the following properties:
1) calculates a unique value for each different set of card ranks
2) is symmetric in the sense that it doesn't depend on the order of the cards
The purpose of this is to reduce the number of elements needed in the lookup table.

A neat way of doing this is to assign a prime number to each rank (2->2, 3->3, 4->5, 5->7, 6->11, 7->13, 8->17, 9->19, T->23, J->29, Q->31, K->37, A->41), and then calculate the product of the primes. For example if the cards are 39TJQQ, then the hash is 36536259.

To create the lookup table you go through all the possible combinations of ranks, and use some simple algorithm to determine whether they form a straight draw. For each combination you also calculate the hash value and then store the results in a map where Key is the hash and Value is the result of the straight draw check. If the maximum number of cards is small (4 or less) then even a linear array might be feasible.

To use the lookup table you first calculate the hash for the particular set of cards and then read the corresponding value from the map.

Here's an example in C++. I don't guarantee that it's working correctly and it could probably be optimized a lot by using a sorted array and binary search instead of hash_map. hash_map is kinda slow for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <hash_map>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

const int MAXCARDS = 9;
stdext::hash_map<long long, bool> lookup;

//"Hash function" that is unique for a each set of card ranks, and also
//symmetric so that the order of cards doesn't matter.
long long hash(const vector<int>& cards)
{
    static const int primes[52] = {
        2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,
        2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,
        2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,
        2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41
    };

    long long res=1;
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i=cards.begin();i!=cards.end();i++)
        res *= primes[*i];
    return res;
}

//Tests whether there is a straight draw (assuming there is no
//straight). Only used for filling the lookup table.
bool is_draw_slow(const vector<int>& cards)
{
    int ranks[14];
    memset(ranks,0,14*sizeof(int));

    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i=cards.begin();i!=cards.end();i++)
        ranks[ *i % 13 + 1 ] = 1;
    ranks[0]=ranks[13]; //ace counts also as 1

    int count = ranks[0]+ranks[1]+ranks[2]+ranks[3];
    for(int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
        count += ranks[i+4];
        if(count==4)
            return true;
        count -= ranks[i];
    }

    return false;
};

void create_lookup_helper(vector<int>& cards, int idx)
{
    for(;cards[idx]<13;cards[idx]++) {
        if(idx==cards.size()-1)
            lookup[hash(cards)] = is_draw_slow(cards);
        else {
            cards[idx+1] = cards[idx];
            create_lookup_helper(cards,idx+1);
        }
    }
}

void create_lookup()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=MAXCARDS;i++) {
        vector<int> cards(i);
        create_lookup_helper(cards,0);
    }
}

//Test for a draw using the lookup table
bool is_draw(const vector<int>& cards)
{
    return lookup[hash(cards)];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    create_lookup();

    cout<<lookup.size()<<endl; //497419

    int cards1[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int cards2[] = {0,1,2,7,12};
    int cards3[] = {3,16,29,42,4,17,30,43};

    cout << is_draw(vector<int>(cards1,cards1+4)) <<endl; //true
    cout << is_draw(vector<int>(cards2,cards2+5)) <<endl; //true
    cout << is_draw(vector<int>(cards3,cards3+8)) <<endl; //false

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually using this approach (primes) for my evaluation code (using gperf to create perfect hash LU tables), I haven't done the calculation to see how much adding draws to the table would add (if anything), but I'm a bit antsy to do this, as the hash tables are quite large at present.  I'm eventually hoping to move to a 7 card evaluation routine to speed things up for some calculations, so I may double back and incorporate it at this point.  Good input!

Answer (score 3):

This may be a naive solution, but I am pretty sure it would work, although I am not sure about the perfomance issues.

Assuming again that the cards are represented by the numbers 1 - 13, then if your 4 cards have a numeric range of 3 or 4 (from highest to lowest card rank) and contain no duplicates then you have a possible straight draw.

A range of 3 implies you have an open-ended draw eg 2,3,4,5 has a range of 3 and contains no duplicates.

A range of 4 implies you have a gutshot (as you called it) eg 5,6,8,9 has a range of 4 and contains no duplicates.

Comment: I think so too.  I had thought about this approach originally, but worried about having to remove duplicates (not a huge deal), but if we have 7 unique ranks, we end up having to check the range for 7 choose 4 combinations.  There could be a trick remove some of those combinations though, going to think about it a bit more.

Comment: This is what I intended up doing.  I realized I wasn't going to be doing a huge multiway test for draws, so it didn't need to be as snappy as my evaluation code.  I neglected to consider double gut shots in my original post, I handled those by counting the number of gut shots in a 5 card set.

Answer (score 0):

Update: per Christian Mann's comment... it can be this:

let's say, `A` is represented as `1`.  `J` as 11, `Q` as 12, etc.

```
loop through 1 to 13 as i
  if my cards already has this card i, then don't worry about this case, skip to next card
  for this card i, look to the left for number of consecutive cards there is
  same as above, but look to the right
  if count_left_consecutive + count_right_consecutive == 4, then found case
```

you will need to define the functions to look for the count of left consecutive cards and right consecutive cards... and also handle the case when when looking right consecutive, after `K`, the `A` is consecutive.

Comment: That will give a false positive at the edges (Aces and Twos). In -addition, it doesn't check at all for gutshots (like 5-6-8-9).

Comment: ok, fixed... although if i am writing this program i will try and debug for any error